# Indefinite imperative in German

Tags: english-to-german, imperative

Grateful for all the help I've been getting on this forum. Here is a sentence in English:

> “Look at all of you!” said Mama Duck with joy.  “You are all so cute!”

How does one form this "indefinite imperative"(I presume) in German?

Answer (score 1):

It's

> Schaut euch (doch) alle (mal) an!

Those modal particles *doch* and *mal* convey Mama Ducks joy. They are not stricly required but without them, it's a rather harsh command.

Comment: I think there's a bit of a figure of speech here; the Mama Duck isn't literally telling them to look an themselves, in which case your answer would be correct. Instead, she's using the phrase "Look at" to emphasize the next phrase. Another example: "Look at that mountain, it's so tall." The imperative isn't addressed to anyone in particular, so I can see why the German impersonal imperative might seem plausible as a translation, but I doubt a German speaker would use it that way. I'm thinking a rephrase is in order.

Comment: It's *Schau euch doch nur einer mal an!* then.

Comment: What I had in mind was to drop "schauen" altogether. Something like "Meine Güte, ihr seid doch so süß!"

Comment: *Was seid ihr süß!* but that's the second part.